# NetBeans lexer throws exception recognizing trailing whitespace

Tags: java, netbeans, antlr, antlr4, netbeans-platform

I have a simple grammar written in ANTLR4 that includes (among others) a whitespace rule:

```
WhiteSpace : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

This is integrated into a NetBeans platform application using `org.netbeans.spi.lexer.Lexer`. When the input has trailing whitespace (before EOF), I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Lexer ExpressionLexer@2cdea2eb
  returned null token but lexerInput.readLength()=1
  lexer-state: null
  tokenStartOffset=20, readOffset=21, lookaheadOffset=22
  Chars: "\n" - these characters need to be tokenized.
Fix the lexer to not return null token in this state.
```

How can I make this trailing whitespace not cause an error?

**Edit:** This works correctly without error using only ANTLR lexer and parser code. The error is only when integrating with the NetBeans lexer (and possibly other integrations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `WhiteSpace` rule to send the token to a hidden channel rather than skipping altogether.

```
WhiteSpace : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

The parser won't see the white space, but the NetBeans lexer will be happy that there is a valid token returned for all the input.